How to get the value of one span of multiple span in java and selenium
I have these html code <span class="h4242-intensified"> 1 </span> <span class="h4242-intensified"> 04/24/2024 </span> <span class="h4242-intensified"> </span> HISTORY ACCOUNT <span class="h4242-intensified"> 18:30</span> <span class="h4242-intensified"> </span> Account <span class=h4242-intensified> </span> 0000021234112
I want to get <span class=h4242-intensified> </span> 0000021234112 and change the color to black.
I have these span with the same class name <span class="h4242-hidden"> </span> <span class="h4242-hidden">R </span>this value 0000021234112 can be change between each search
I have tried with with List<WebElement> Listspan = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span") but I don't know how get the value 0000021234112 and change the color
